# Access R Shiny application not with an IP

Tags: r, shiny

I have developed a R Shiny app and hosted on a local intranet server and my colleagues are able to access it using the IP:Port no like http://192.168.135.146:5050/

But what if I need to replace this with a name like myshinyapp.com. I know I am missing something very trivial, pls help. Thanks

Comment: You need to set-up `nginx` or `apache2` to have a pretty names on your server

Answer (score 1):

1) Edit `hosts` file

For `Windows7` users go to your IT and ask them to edit the `hosts` file located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`.

2) Get your IP address from `ipconfig` using `cmd`

3) Insert a new line to DNS like so:

[image]

You should be able to access your app by name then

Alternatevly install `nginx` or `apache2` on your `shiny-server`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Is it true that one can bind only the IP address and not the port number with a pretty name. Now with IP address only getting bind I am able to access it like http://myprettyname.com:5050 and not without 5050 at the end. Any solution here. Thanks