# R Shiny App IP Change

Tags: r, networking, shiny

So I am currently deploying my shiny app via the runapp function so people can view it by accessing my IP and port in which the app is broadcast on. The only issue is my IP changes consistently if I am leased out a new address so I have to continually send out a new link. Is there any way around this so even if my IP changes the link to the shiny app remains the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access R Shiny application not with an IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052143/access-r-shiny-application-not-with-an-ip)

Comment: @PorkChop - the one you're referring to, would it help when the IP changes? I am not sure.

Comment: If you overwrite localhost with either a name or an IP it should work, however I havent tested it. Its best if you run a shiny-server instead and access it by name

Comment: I don't believe I can override my local host name so I don't think this would be an option